# xhr onloadend isn't fired when using https

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following html page (unabridged):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="f" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#f').change(function () {
            let formData = new FormData(), file = this.files[0];
            formData.append('upload', file);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/fi/upload',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                xhr: function () {
                    var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    xhr.upload.onloadend = function (e) {
                        debugger; //doesn't get here when using https
                    };
                    return xhr;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When calling the page using http, the `onloadend` callback fires. When using https, it doesn't. It's the same story with `onprogress`.

`/fi/upload` doesn't do anything - it's an empty C# MVC action returning `void`. It returns code `200` for both http & https.

Why is this? Can anyone reproduce this?

Comment: sorry if i sound odd but what is the `url` that you use with `https`.

Comment: `https://somedomain/t.htm`. `somedomain` is mapped to `127.0.0.1` in `hosts`.

Comment: try to reproduce this on fiddle

Comment: you are using virtual host, have you configured ssl on your local machine can you open the page in your browser with https?

Comment: yes of course, the page loads, and I see the file upload control